# Multi-select and deselect of columns - jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to write the content of one or more columns into an array. It should be also possible to deselect a column. I use the following code to address the column, but now I don't know how to get the content.

```
$("td").click(function () {
    var columnNo = $(this).index();
    $(this).closest("table")
        .find("tr td:nth-child(" + (columnNo + 1) + ")")
        .css("color", "red");
});
```

[example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9msE/)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = [];
$("td").click(function () {
    var columnNo = $(this).index();
    $(this).closest("table")
        .find("tr td:nth-child(" + (columnNo + 1) + ")")
        .toggleClass("selected");
    var val = $(this).closest("table")
        .find("tr td:nth-child(" + (columnNo + 1) + ")").text(); // to get column text
    if($(this).hasClass( "selected" )){ //to check whether user selected or not
        if($.inArray(val,text)<0){ //check value exists in array
            text.push(val);
        }
    }else{
        text.splice($.inArray(val, text),1); //if user deselect remove column text from array
    }
    console.log(text);
});
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X9msE/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/E7AM6/)

```
$("td").click(function () {
    var columnNo = $(this).index();
    var $arr = $(this).closest("table")
        .find("tr td:nth-child(" + (columnNo + 1) + ")")
        .toggleClass("selected").map(function() {
            return ($(this).hasClass('selected')) ? $(this).text() : "";
          }).get();
    console.log($arr);//$arr is the array of TD values of a column you've clicked
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class / custom attribute to the elements.
And pick them by using class Name.

```
 $(this).closest("table").find("tr td:nth-child(" + (columnNo + 1) + ")").addClass('yourOwnClassName');
```

All the *td* can be fetched using the class name.
Also give id to you table.

```
var selectedRows =$('#mytable .yourOwnClassName');
```

And to Select and Deselect you can add css to you class.
So adding and removing class would do the job of showing selected Content.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td").click(function () {
    var columnNo = $(this).index();
    $(this).closest("table")
        .find("tr td:nth-child(" + (columnNo + 1) + ")")
        .css("color", "red");
var array1 = [];
    for(var i = 0;i <= ($("table tr").length - 1); i++){
        array1[i] = $("table").find("tr:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")").find("td:nth-child(" + (columnNo + 1) + ")").text();
        };
        alert(array1);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X9msE/7/)